# AS3 SecurityPanel not showing when hardware acceleration is used

Tags: actionscript-3, webcam

If I publish Windows Projector (.exe) with no hardware acceleration, everything works fine, but if I select direct or gpu harware acceleration I will not get the security panel to show up at all. Anyone else have this same issue, or is it just me?
Basically I would like to publish a stand-alone webcam game, but if I try to use getCamera(), the user will not see the security question at all, and I will not get the camera initialized.
Does anyone know a workaround for this? I would love to get HW acceleration to my game.

```
import flash.system.Security;
import flash.system.SecurityPanel;
//import flash.media.Camera;

Security.showSettings(SecurityPanel.CAMERA);
//var camera:Camera=Camera.getCamera();
```

Comment: I never really had a need to make a projector before but is hardware acceleration supported in projectors? I thought that was a browser specific thing.

Answer (score 0):

I got this to work, but I created a projector through the stand alone and the "Create Projector" menu, not through the Flash IDE.  I was able to get the panel to show up using the latest flash.

compiler settings: -swf-version=16 -use-gpu=true

// test showing stage3D + panel
final public class Test extends Sprite {

```
    private var cam:Camera;
    private var video:Video = new Video();

    public function Test():void {

        var stage3D:Stage3D = stage.stage3Ds[0];
        stage3D.addEventListener(Event.CONTEXT3D_CREATE, handleContext);
        stage3D.requestContext3D();

        trace(cam.name);
    }

    /**
     *  @private
     */
    private function handleContext(e:Event):void {
        var stage3D:Stage3D     = stage.stage3Ds[0];
        var context:Context3D   = stage3D.context3D;
        context.configureBackBuffer(stage.stageWidth, stage.stageHeight, 0, true);
        context.clear(0,0,0,1);
        context.present();

        Security.showSettings(SecurityPanel.CAMERA);

        cam = Camera.getCamera();
        cam.setMode(640,360,30);
        video.attachCamera(cam);

        // change to upload via texture instead
        addChild(video);
    }
```

In my experience, hardware acceleration gains are only very minimal without using specific gpu apis.  Camera in my experience instead accelerated, only specific types of video decompression.  If you're not using Stage3D, you probably won't get any visible gains.